Cyclical issues where an object field
I have a cyclic issue between a flow and 3 custom checkbox fields and I need to know how to resolve it.
I had accidentally created 3 checkbox fields on a Call Center object and added these 3 fields to an assignment statement in a Screen Flow. The flow version was at version 6 before I began making my updates.

I activated the flow but discovered that those fields were not needed
in this flow's Assignment element. So, I deactivated the flow and saw that both the Activate
and Save buttons were grayed out while the Save As button was
accessible/clickable.

This meant that when I tried to remove those 3 fields within the flow's Assignment element, I was forced to click Save As to update the flow to the next version (version 7) instead of simply saving it at the current version. This was not what I wanted.

When I try to remove the 3 fields , Salesforce did not let me delete
them due to the previous version 6. The error message I got was: This
custom field is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. (with a link
to flow version 6)
When I tried to delete version 6 of my Screen Flow I got the following
error:This flow version is referenced elsewhere in Salesforce.
Remove the usage and try again. and it gives me the link of the
problematic flow (version 6).

How do I successfully remove these 3 fields without having to refresh the sandbox and lose any other work that I have done which is unrelated to this flow?  Thanks

After rummaging around google searching, I found the answer here having to do with Paused and Failed flow interviews: Trailhead Community
As soon as I checked the Pasued and Failed Flow Interviews I saw version 6 and deleted it.  It also allowed me to:

Delete flow version 6
Remove those 3 unnecessary fields from the Call Center object.
I hope this helps anyone who is having the same issue I had.

